# Meteor session variable not getting last character on keyup

Tags: meteor, typeahead, keyup

I'm having an issue with a Session variable that I am using to keep track of a search query when using alongside the Meteor Typeahead package.

When I log the variable in the console the last character displays but when I output my helper in the template that Typeahead calls, it omits the last character.

My event:

```
Template.bookSearchForm.events
  'keyup .typeahead': (e) ->
    bookVal = e.target.value 
    Session.set 'bookSearchValue', bookVal
```

My helper:

```
Template.searchNoItems.helpers
  bookSearchValue: ->
   return Session.get 'bookSearchValue'
```

My template:

```
<template name="searchNoItems">
  <div class="search-no-results">
   <span class="lookupBook">Search for {{ bookSearchValue }}</span>
  </div> <!-- /.search-no-results -->
</template>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Just to confirm, the console is spitting out the full query eg: "My Query" whereas in the helper it's only outputting: "My Quer".

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I think we may need to see more of your code... I did a quick MeteorPad of something similar and cannot reproduce the behavior that you are seeing. (but I am seeing a different bad behavior of keyup obviously not being fired when you don't hit a key after the typeahead autocompletes)
http://meteorpad.com/pad/vWxyngjoCZh8CYhKj/Test

Comment: @craigts That's brilliant, thanks so much for reproducing this, your example clearly works so I will have to see where my code deviates!

Comment: @craigts One difference I see is that I'm declaring the searchNoItems template using the data attributes in the input tag - data-templates="searchItem;empty:searchNoItems" If I output the template manually the query appears to be correct.

Comment: I recommend `change .typeahead` instead of `keyup .typeahead` - this will let you deal with pasted-in text cleanly.

Comment: Thanks @michel-floyd, actually change doesn't seem to trigger anything for me?

Comment: Oh, so sorry, I meant `input .typeahead`! It's been awhile since I touched that bit.

Comment: Thanks Michel, this doesn't appear to affect the missing last character, I'm thinking it must be related to the Typeahead function somehow, I will post an issue on the repo.

Answer (score 0):

use this `{{{ bookSearchValue }}}` notice it's 3 curly braces

> Handlebars/Spacebars HTML-escapes values returned by a
>   `{{expression}}`. If you don't want to escape a value, use the
>   "triple-stash", `{{{`

Comment: Thanks Mark but the helper is outputting text, just not the last character. The third brace doesn't seem to change this?

Comment: @onjegolders did you give it a try? When you `console.log(Session.get('bookSearchValue'))` you get correct value right? But when you use the helper and output with `{{` it's not the correct text? The only thing I see here is `{{{` issue ir you get the seasion modified somewhere else or for goot measure you can try to return `Session.get('bookSearchValue').toString()`

Comment: Thanks, yes I did try your suggestion, also the toString suggestion but sadly it's the same result each time, the last character is not included. Perhaps it's Meteor Typeahead package somehow not updating correctly?

Comment: @onjegolders yes possibly, the problem is in `keyup .typehead` try to get  the value like this: `$(e.currentTarget).val()` and add `console.log('keyup called');` to see if keyup gets called again possibly and removing the last character

Comment: Interesting. On keyup, it's logging twice for the first character so that may explain the lack of a final character if the tally is wrong.

If I change it to keypress, the tally is correct, however the helper is still one character behind unfortunately.